# Formatted array is present but points wont plot

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have hit a road block in trying to make a map. 
The geojson formatted array is coming over to JS with no problem per console logging.

However, I cant seem to figure out how to get this code to work.

```
var js_var;
$.get("my_file.php", function(data) {
      js_var=data;
       console.log(js_var)
});
  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = "<p>I started out as a GeoJSON " +
                feature.geometry.coordinates + ", but now I'm a Leaflet vector!</p>";

        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.prop1) {
            popupContent += feature.properties.prop2;
        }

        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }


  L.geoJSON(feature, {

        style: function (feature) {
            return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
        },

        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: 8,
                fillColor: "#ff7800",
                color: "#000",
                weight: 1,
                opacity: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.8
            });
        }
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

My geojson looks like this:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"Features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "prop1": "value",
            "prop2": "value",

        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": "[-89.853567,39.840856]"
        }
    },
```

I have looked at supporting documentation but can't figure this out.

view-source:http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/example.html
http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/sample-geojson.js

What am I missing?

EDIT: I found a different example to work off of, yet still no luck.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    // does this feature have a property named popupContent?
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.prop1) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.prop1);
    }
}

var js_var;
$.get("my_file.php", function(data) {
      js_var=data;
    console.log(js_var)
});


L.geoJSON(js_var, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the data after it is retrieved by `$.get()`, except to log it. That is, you don't use `js_var` anywhere else - but note that `$.get()` is asynchronous, so you'd need to use it within the `$.get()` callback or from other other functions called from that callback.

Comment: Please don't post blocks of code in comments, it's very hard to read. [Edit] your question to show the relevant code there. Anyway, have you tried putting the `L.geoJSON(js_var, ...)` code *inside* the `$.get()` handler right after the `console.log()`? As I mentioned before, `$.get()` is asynchronous, which means that in the code you've shown the `L.geoJSON()` call happens *before* the data is returned from the server.

Comment: I added the `onEachFunction` and `L.geoJSON(js_var)` right after the `console.log()`   Console shows "invalid geojson object"

Comment: I think it goes back to "coordinates" = "[lat, long]". Need to get rid of quotes I think.

Answer (score 1):

When you are expecting JSON you'll need to set the `dataType` option to `json` or use `$.getJSON` which does that for you:

```
$.getJSON('my_file.php', function (json) {
    // here 'json' is a JSON object
});
```

Next you have to keep in mind that XHR functions `$.get`, `$.post` etc are asyncronous functions. You'll need to wait for it to resolve before you can use it. For example:

```
// This gets executed first
var geojson;

// This is second
$.getJSON('my_file.php', function (json) {
    // This needs to load so will be fourth
    geojson = json;
});

// Third, at which point 'geojson = json' has not been
// executed yet so it fails.
new L.GeoJSON(geojson);
```

Put your logic into the callback function of `$.getJSON` and it just works™:

```
$.getJSON('my_file.php', function (json) {
    new L.GeoJSON(json);
});
```

Comment: Please see edit 2 in the original post. Trying to update the query within the PHP with a dropdown value. The log shows the post is updating the query properly. However, I keep getting an invalid GEOJSON object.

Comment: Sorry about that! Your answer did work! Thanks for that. I'll ask a new question and answer it myself as I solved it and it may help future users!